# Power Query - Filter by specific individual Key per row

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

He experts!
I'm working in Power Query at reducing the amount of data that is loaded into the model later.
I have a big transactional table that contains multiple rows per Order:
[image]

The objective is to get the MAX Value (Last) column based on this filter for each Order:
[image]

As we can see for instance, the MAX Value for with the Type 1 = A1 is based on Key 1 = 50 and Key 2 = 20, regardless of Type 2. And so on.

Is there any chance to get this done within Power Query?
The result would be like that:

[image]

Comment: What if `Type1=A1` and `Type2="C"`.  Which rule takes priority - The `A1` rule or the `A*` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated because of the wildcard

If you set up your Rules table as shown here (and name the query **Rules**)

[image]

then this code should work

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
        let r = _ in Table.MatchesAnyRows(
            Rules,
            each List.Contains({r[Type 1], "*"}, [Type 1])
            and List.Contains({r[Type 2], "*"}, [Type 2])
            and List.Contains({r[Key 1], "*"}, [Key 1])
            and List.Contains({r[Key 2], "*"}, [Key 2])
    )),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = true)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Order"}, {{"Value", each List.Max([Value]), type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

this is the intermediate step being created before the group and max

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a discrete Type 1 takes priority over a "wild card" Type 1, you might be able to deal with by doing `.FuzzyNestedJoin`, although, depending on your actual data, you might have to adjust the `threshold` from the default of `0.8`

Also, depending on your actual data, you might want to change some of the data types (integer vs decimal number, etc).

Then

- Group by Order
- Create a filter using a comparison of the Type and Key columns
- Return the MAX of the Value column

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filter"]}[Content],
    filter = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Type 1", type text}, {"Type 2", type text}, {"Key 1", Int64.Type}, {"Key 2", Int64.Type}}),
    
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Transactions"]}[Content],
    transactions = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Order", Int64.Type},
        {"Type 1", type text},
        {"Type 2", type text},
        {"Key 1", Int64.Type},
        {"Key 2", Int64.Type},
        {"Value", Int64.Type}
    }),

    join = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(transactions,"Type 1", filter,"Type 1","joined",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(join, "joined", 
        {"Type 1", "Type 2", "Key 1", "Key 2"}, {"joined.Type 1", "joined.Type 2", "joined.Key 1", "joined.Key 2"}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded joined", {"Order"}, {
        {"Value", (t)=> List.Max(Table.SelectRows(t, each (([joined.Type 2]=null) or ([Type 2]=[joined.Type 2])) and 
                [Key 1]=[joined.Key 1] and [Key 2]=[joined.Key 2])[Value]), Int64.Type}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]